# Kotlin - Companion Object changes it value when the variable is changed

Tags: kotlin, companion-object

I am having a data class which is having data in form of Lists (Companion Objects). I assign these lists to my variables (lists) in Activity class according to my requirement.
The problem is that when I change some list (that was assigned the companion object list value) in Activity class then Companion object list is also changed.
Why is this happening? Are Companion objects as assigned by reference? How to avoid this?
I want if the variable list of Activity class is changed then companion object list should retain its value.

My code
Data List

```
class DataLists {
    companion object {
        val CountryList: List<CountryDataStructure> = listOf(
            CountryDataStructure(1, "USA"),
            CountryDataStructure(2, "Canada"))
    }
}
```

Activity Class

```
var CountryData = DataLists.CountryList
CountryData[0].Name = "United States of America" 
//Here the Companion object list (CountryList) i.e. DataList is also changed and have 
//values "United States of America" and "Canada" while I expect this to have "USA" and "Canada"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything besides inline classes and primitives is *always* passed by a reference copy, not a deep value copy. Inline classes and primitives are sometimes passed by value copy, but the distinction hardly matters since they're immutable.

Since your `CountryDataStructure` class is mutable, you need to manually copy both the list and  the items in the list, which can be done using the `map` iterator function and the data class `copy()` function:

```
val countryData = DataLists.CountryList.map { it.copy() }
countryData[0].Name = "United States of America"
```